# How to use endpoint, but remove/rewrite endpoint base?

Tags: rewrite-rules, parameter, query-variable, endpoints

I've been messing around with rewrites and `query_var` to generate some listings, for example:

- ~/my-page/?my_var=1
- ~/my-page/?my_var=2
- ~/my-page/?my_var=3

After perusing StackExchange and the interwebs a bit, it seems that the overwhelming consensus is that [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) is the way to go. As such, I've implemented the following:

```
function wpd_add_my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my_var', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_my_endpoint' );
```

This yields the following URIs based on the ones I mentioned previously:

- ~/my-page/my_var/1
- ~/my-page/my_var/2
- ~/my-page/my_var/3

However, I would like to strip out the 'endpoint base' (or slug, not even sure what to call this exactly, in this question/example 'my_var'), so that the URIs would be:

- ~/my-page/1/
- ~/my-page/2/
- ~/my-page/3/

I've tried a bunch of different ways to do rewrites, but none to any avail, this is what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
function setup_filter_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule('my-page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
```

**Updated**

My code in it's entirety is now:

```
// Add Query Var
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "my_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

// Add Endpoint
function wpd_add_my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my_var', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_my_endpoint' );

// Add Rewrite
function setup_filter_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^my-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
```

With the above code, ~/my-page/my_var/1/ works, but ~/my-page/1/ returns a 404. (I have flushed permalinks)

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `add_rewrite_rule` is the correct route to go and I think what you have is correct also barring the Regex.

Try substituting what you have currently for this => `^my-page\/([0-9]+)\/?`.

Full code below:

```
function setup_filter_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^my-page\/([0-9]+)\/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
```

Comment: You also need to register custom query var: [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Custom_Query_Vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Custom_Query_Vars)

Comment: @KrzysztofGrabania is very much correct, completely forgot that

Comment: thanks @Alex Baulch. I've updated the question with the bit to register the custom query var and the corrected regex. However, the page is kicking out a 404. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a bit of tweaking and messing about, I have the following code which seems to work:

```
// Add Query Var
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "my_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

// Add Endpoint
function wpd_add_my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my_var', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_my_endpoint' );

// Add Rewrite Rule
function myplugin_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^my-page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=my-page&my_var=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```